# Make the background of a flex until the end of the flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I need the background of the flexbox to continue past the screen width, with the scroll. I can't attribute `overflow:auto` to `.elements` or `.line1/2` because I want the scrollbar at the bottom of the screen (because it's a simplified version of a complicated project).

```css
.line1{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row;
    background-color: red;
}
.line2{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row;
    background-color: blue;
}
.elements{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="line1">
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="line2">
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.elements` as `inline-flex`:

```css
.elements {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.line1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  background-color: red;
}

.line2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="line1">
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="line2">
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
    <h1>HiMyNameIsRickAstley</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much !